# Android power off screen destroys app when landscaped

Tags: android, google-maps, sleep, screen-orientation

I'm tracking locations using the google api, if I power off the screen in portrait mode and power back on, my map is still there and my locations were still being recorded while the screen was powered off (the desired effect). If I power off in landscape and power on in portrait, onDestroy has been called (not desired). The MapActivity is trying to recycle the map object and just throws a fatal. How should I handle this?

Comment: Try changing the onConfigchange options in Manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can try using this!!!

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Comment: I applied android:configChanges="orientation" in the manifest and that worked perfect! This change now executes the InstanceState methods and does not fire the onDestroy... that's great but why does onDestroy fire when you power off the screen w/o the manifest change. Just curious. Thanks jinsi